# How to make an invisible sprite in pygame? (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

to elaborate, I'm currently creating a maze layout using wall sprites. however, I want the maze to be invisible when I am actually playing the game, while still able to be able to have collision detection. Is this possible in any way? Thanks.

Comment: Since there is not "invisible" in the computer and transparent only show that is below, what you want might be a simple single color sprite, maybe with edges it your maze is a grid.

Comment: just don't render the sprites?

Comment: Just make the sprites the same colour as the background?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using images to show your walls? Because if you are, you can use a program called paint.net to create a transparent sprite. Just create a file with the desired dimensions and use the eraser tool to make the whole thing transparent (click on the little squiggly arrow up at the top to make it easier). Save it as a png in your pygame folder and you have a transparent square.

Comment: @H. Chen: You can also use GIMP, a professional quality free graphics program.